# How to take inputs in same line in Python which is inside a loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, user-input

How to give the no. of elements and the list in the same line? Following is the sample:

```
1
8
234 567 321 345 123 110 767 111
```

Here I want to ask the user to how many elements does he/she wants that's N and after specifying that I want the user to input the elements in the same line in which he/she inputted N.

```
T = int(input())
for x in range(T):
    N = int(input())
    nums = list(map(int, input().split()))
```

Here with this code I am able to give N and nums in different lines but I want them in same line and then evaluate the solution.
Here's the full code:

```
def largest(num):
    num_str = str(num)
    i = 9
    while i >= 0:
        if str(i) in num_str:
            return i
        i -= 1


def smallest(num):
    num_str = str(num)
    i = 0
    while i <= 9:
        if str(i) in num_str:
            return i
        i += 1


def pairs(num):
    if num == 2:
        return 1
    if num == 3:
        return 2
    return 0


T = int(input())
for x in range(T):
    N = int(input())
    nums = list(map(int, input().split()))

    assert(len(nums) == N)

    bitscore = [""]*N

    for i in range(len(bitscore)):
        curr_score = str(11 * largest(nums[i]) + 7 * smallest(nums[i]))
        if len(curr_score) > 2:
            curr_score = curr_score[-2:]
        bitscore[i] = curr_score

    odd_pos_freq = [0] * 10
    even_pos_freq = [0] * 10

    for i in range(len(bitscore)):
        index = int(bitscore[i][0])
        if (i + 1) % 2 == 0:
            even_pos_freq[index] += 1
        else:
            odd_pos_freq[index] += 1

    count_pairs = [0] * 10

    for i in range(10):
        if even_pos_freq[i] <= 1 and odd_pos_freq[i] <= 1:
            continue
        count_pairs[i] += pairs(even_pos_freq[i]) + pairs(odd_pos_freq[i])
        count_pairs[i] = min(2, count_pairs[i])

    print(sum(count_pairs))
```

I know this question may sound stupid but many a times I have been stuck at such small things and even with correct logic I am unable to submit correct answer.

Comment: If the user enters less than what he/she has specified, what do you want to do?

Comment: You can just read one line with N and all the numbers and split them. Index 0 is N.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your code:

```
N = int(input())
nums = list(map(int, input().split()))
```

with:

```
line = input('')
nums = list(map(int, line.split()))
N = nums[0]
nums = nums[1:]
```

Comment: I am unable to evaluate the answer after giving this bit of code.

Comment: I want to give input like this 8 234 567 321 345 123 110 767 111 and then evaluate the code.

Comment: Just read the entire line, convert to integers. The first element is N. The rest are the numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was stuck in this for quite some time